# Hacker News style ordering algorithm in Linq-To-SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

According to [this site](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/reddit-stumbleupon-delicious-and-hacker-news-algorithms-exposed) the ordering algorithm for hacker news goes something like this:

> (p - 1) / (t + 2)^1.5
>
> Description:
>
> Votes divided by age factor
>
> p = votes (points) from users. t =
>   time since submission in hours.
>
> p is subtracted by 1 to negate
>   submitters vote. age factor is (time
>   since submission in hours plus two) to
>   the power of 1.5.

Given a table structure similar to this:

> **Item**
>   ID
>   Link
>   DatePosted
>
> **Item_Votes**
>   ItemID
>   Value

What would be the best way to implement the algorithm using linq to sql, would I be able to write the query entirely in linq or would I need to use a stored procedure or something else.

Update. Ended up using the code below based off TJB's answer:

```
    var votesQuery =
        from i in db.Items
        join v in db.Item_Votes on i.ItemID equals v.ItemID
        orderby
            (double)(v.Value - 1) /
                    Math.Pow(
                        (DateTime.Now - i.DatePosted.Value).TotalHours + 2,
                    1.5) descending
        select i;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using <strike>2</strike> 1 Linq querie<strike>s</strike> (there's probably **still** a more efficent way)

```
var votesQuery =
    from i in items
    join v in votes on i.Id equals v.ItemId
    orderby
        (v.Value - 1) / 
                Math.Pow( 
                    (DateTime.Now - i.Posted).Add(new TimeSpan(2,0,0)).Hours, 
                1.5 )
    select new
    {
        Item = i,
        Vote = v
    };
```

Comment: thanks mate using something very similar to this and its working well

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Comparer`.  This will allow you to write the logic for the comparisons between rows any way you want.

Here is an example, using case-insensitive ordering:

```
public void LinqExample()
{
    string[] words = { 
        "aPPLE", "AbAcUs", "bRaNcH", "BlUeBeRrY", "ClOvEr", "cHeRry" 
    };

    var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(a => a, new CaseInsensitiveComparer());

    ObjectDumper.Write(sortedWords);
}

public class CaseInsensitiveComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This might work (untested):

```
var orderedList = 
    from extracted in (
         from i in unorderedList 
             select new 
             { 
                 Item = i,
                 Order = (p - 1) / Math.Pow(t + 2, 1.5)
             }
             orderby extracted.Order
             select extracted.Item
         ).ToList();
```